# merge table in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have the 2 tables as below

```
subj <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
gamble <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
ev <- c(4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6)
table1 <- data.frame(subj, gamble, ev)

subj2 <- c(1, 2, 3)
gamble2 <- c(1, 3, 2)
table2 <- data.frame(subj2, gamble2)
```

I want to merge the two tables by gamble, only choose the gamble from table 1 which has the same number to gamble in table 2. The expected output is as follows:

```
 sub gamble ev
  1      1  4
  2      3  6
  3      2  5
```

Comment: Folks, if you are going to down vote a brand new user, please leave helpful comments. Otherwise you are just being a dkc

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, I didn't down vote, and I agree in principle with your comment, but this question *does* deserve a down vote for a couple of reasons. First, one criteria for down voting = "does not show any research effort". How could the OP miss `merge` in their research? Second, the OP could have taken the time to format their post correctly, check their spelling, and so on *especially because* they are a brand new user (ie: don't anger those who want to help you for free too early in the game!)

Comment: @AnandaMahto, completely agree.   And in fact my point was exactly to encourage the ideas you highlight.    Simply clicking the downvote and moving on helps nobody.  Figuring out how to properly format a SO question takes time.  Figuring out what makes a good question takes experience and input from everybody.   If instead of (or at best, in _addition to_) downvoting, the person would have left a comment as to how the question could be improved then everyone would benefit

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `merge`

```
 merge(table1, table2, by.x=c("subj", "gamble"), by.y=c("subj2", "gamble2"), all=FALSE, sort=TRUE)
```

*edited as per Ananda's helpful observation*

Comment: thank you very much, but i tried the code, the table doesnt look like the way i want.. i want to look like                          sub gamble ev
   1      1  4
   2      3  6
   3      2  5
can you help please...

Comment: @elvita, try `merge(table1, table2, by.x = c("subj", "gamble"), by.y = c("subj2", "gamble2"))`

Comment: @AnandaMahto, not sure how you caught that from the description... !